# Dollar sign becomes MathJax on top network posts

Tags: bug, profile-page, mathjax, top-network-posts

This is basically the same issue as these (all of them are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) at the moment):

- [Dollar sign used as currency renders incorrectly in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239345/dollar-sign-used-as-currency-renders-incorrectly-in-android-app)
- [Dollar signs breaks formatting of 'Hot Network Questions'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/dollar-signs-breaks-formatting-of-hot-network-questions)
- [Exclude TeX.SE question titles from MathJax parsing in Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions)

But in the "Top network post" section on the profile page:

[image: Dollar sign turns into MathJax bug]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303405/difference-between-html-body-animate-and-body-animate/19738288#19738288)'s title on [this profile](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16011/joe) becomes MathJax

Comment: Ask CM's to turn Mathjax off on Worldbuilding.SE ;)

Comment: @Luuklag guess things would become really tricky if this user decided to create profile at Math.SE :)